# matplotlib.pyplot title adjusts number of digits to display in floating points

Tags: python, matplotlib, floating-point, title

I have been searched high and low to display only 2 digits of floating points.  Here is a variable "enrichment", which is equal to 31.5925925926.......  Is there any way just to display the following in matplotlib.pyplot?

Desired plot title:

```
ROC Curve; Enrichment factor 1% = 31.59
```

Here is the code

```
plt.title('ROC Curve; Enrichment factor 1% = '+str(enrichment))
```

This will show

```
ROC Curve; Enrichment factor 1% = 31.5925925926
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Matplotlib is irrelevant here. Just use string formatting

`plt.title('ROC Curve; Enrichment factor 1% = {:.2f}'.format(enrichment))`

Comment: Hi Paul, what is the key word for the corresponding python module? "= {:.2f}"

Comment: @Chubaka it's just a method of string objects. google search: "python string formatting"